# Array with Scanner

Tags: java, arrays

Please help my prof is not teaching well 
my prof wants me that the user will enter the value of its Index and Elements i tried doing 2 for loops but it wont work

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Arrays 
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {   
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

        int index;
        int elements;

        System.out.println("Input Array Size");
        index = sc.nextInt();


        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) 
        {
            System.out.println("Array Index is =\t"+index);
            System.out.println ("Insert the Elements of the Array");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

*If anyone knows a link for this please send me i badly need your help i need to Learn input search and delete in an array but with the use of Scanner hayst pls help me -Student*

Comment: Seriously. If you're going to dump an assignment on this Q&A-page, atleast make sure it's formatted properly. You didn't even tell us the problem you're facing. We don't provide a "codez for phr33"-service here, we answer (more or less) specific questions. Don't blame it on your prof., the internet is big & has a lot of knowledge to offer.

Comment: its not an assignment its a task given a while ago that i cant even answer anyway thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you're just printing the array size, while not taking in any input to fill the array. The actual way to do this is as follows.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Arrays
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //Create a Scanner to read input
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Promt the user to enter the array size and store the input
        System.out.println("Enter the size of the array:");
        int arraySize = scan.nextInt();

        //Create an array (For this example we'll use an integer array)
        int[] array = new int[arraySize];

        //Create a for loop to run through array
        for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
        {
            //Prompt the user to enter a number at the current index (i)
            System.out.println("Enter the element at index " + i + ":");

            //Store the input at index i in the array
            array[i] = scan.nextInt();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: WOW FAK AWESOME i didnt even know that i can use this "int[] array = new int[arraySize];" i do only know is when u put that code that will be Static Man Thankyousomuch

Comment: M8 u make me Happy Thankyousomuch do you know any links in youtube? About Adding Searching and deleting an Array but Still with the use of Scanner i u know some can u please give me the link Thankyousomuch now i understand :) <3 Godbless you

Answer (score 1):

You would need to scan for input also in your for loop.  Please have a look at the following code

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
            System.out.print("Input Array Size : ");
            int size = sc.nextInt();

            int[] elements = new int[size];
            System.out.println("Insert "+size+" Elements of the Array");
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                System.out.print("Element "+i+" : ");
                elements[i] = sc.nextInt();
            }

            System.out.println("Provided array:" + Arrays.toString(elements));          
        } finally {
            sc.close();
        }
   }
```